# XCode MVC Clarification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble understanding the MVC concept being talked about in XCode/Cocoa/Objective-C programming.

Is this just a terminology used? Or are there are actually functions in XCode that let you build a well-organized program?

I also can't clarify what is meant by a model, a 'view' and a controller, if someone could clarify that I'd really appreciate it.

I think a model is a data-store, like a database. Ultimately isn't this kept as a normal class file?
Is the view the interface you create in interface builder?
Finally, is the controller just the main code of your program, consisting of several methods?

Sorry if it seems a silly question, coming from shell scripting I just find this all puzzling.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Have you read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14)?

Answer (score 1):

In XCode, you construct views and connect them to controllers. So you could say that it encourages MVC design. The model part is a bit more nebulous.

Comment: so controllers are the objects with classes and methods you create, and the view is the interface which connects to these objects? the model is a separate thing which stores data, etc. Am i right in saying this? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read first two chapters of a book *Cocoa Design Patterns*. It helped me to understand how MVC applies to Cocoa.